# How to use if condition statement with arrays values

Tags: r

Suppose I have an array such this:

```
d=5; N=2

V <- V1 <- array(dim = c(d, d, N))
U <- matrix(runif(N * d), ncol = d)
   for (i in 1:d) {
    V[i, i, ] <- U[, i]
  }
  V[1, 1, ] <- V1[1, 1, ]
```

This will produce the following array:

```
, , 1

          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.6968945   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

, , 2

          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.5170486   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I would like to use `if` condition based on the values at each position in each array. For example,

```
w1 <- c(0,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,
        0,0,0.8,0.9,0.9,
        0,0,0,0.9,0.9,
        0,0,0,0,0.7,
        0,0,0,0,0)
w1 <- matrix(w1,5,5)

for(i in 1:d) {
 if(V[i, i, ] < w1[k,i]){
   print(V[i,i, ]) 
   } else {
     NULL
   }
}
```

I got this:

```
 Error in if (V[i, i, ] < w1[k, i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (V[i, i, ] < w1[k, i]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help, please?

Comment: You can check the length of `V[i,i, ]`  It is greater than 1.  BTW, where is `k` defined?  Perhaps `if(all(V[i, i, ] < w1[i,i] & !is.na(V[i,i,])))`

Comment: You haven't defined `k` in your example. Beware that you take two elements in `V` and one in `w1`. For conditionals try `if(isTRUE(V[i, i, ] < w1[k,i])==TRUE)` instead for.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your comment. `for (k in 1:d)`.